# How to fix BarTextColor on android api >=Kitkat without using styles.axml

Tags: text, xamarin.forms, colors, android-toolbar

I noticed on Android >= KitKat, I couldn`t change the default text color on the toolbar items . all I can change is the background color. I tried everything out here using styles.axml. 
My toolbar background color is white, the text and menu icon have to be blue.On KitKat, everything is white including the text. (On my styles.axml I don't have any color set up in white. so I guess is a default.)
The following solution works fine on all other SDK's 
-> App.xaml

```
 <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
        <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="ffffff"/>
        <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="#1c4d9e"/>
  </Style>
```

--MY WORKAROUND-- since I wasn't able to achieve the color change using styles .xaml. 
 -NOTE- I am only doing as an extreme solution to detect if the SDK is KitKat and just modify the background color of the toolbar. because the text is white. 
My goal is to change the color of every individual element on the toolbar regardless of the SDK

```
public void KitKat() 
      {
        var Check = DependencyService.Get<Interfaces.ISDK>();
        var a = Check.IsKitkat();
        if(a == true) 
        {
           new Setter {Property = NavigationPage.BarBackgroundColorProperty, Value = Color.DarkRed};
           new Setter {Property = NavigationPage.BarTextColorProperty, Value = Color.White};

         }

      }
```

Toolbar example

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem  Text="Help" 
              Order="Primary"  Command="{Binding HelpCommand}" />
           <ToolbarItem  AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree="true"  
          Text="Next" Order="Secondary"  Command="{Binding NextCommand}" />
       </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Comment: Do you want to change the color of `Help`  and `next` in `ToolbarItem `? `BarTextColor` could set the color of tiltle bar like this screenshot.https://imgur.com/a/melpld5, I set `Help` and `next` to read , set the `BarTextColor` to blue. If so, I could achieve it in kitkat  or above kitkat

Comment: Your question is ambiguous please elaborate

Comment: if you did the change on the styles.axml can you share how you did it . also @G.hakim what do you want me to change in the question? not sure

Comment: @Pxaml I have add the styles in answer, you could refer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I changed the `Help` tab By following operations.

1.I add the `secondary_text` item in the `colors.xml`,

`<color name="secondary_text">#DC143C</color>`

2.I add the `<item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/secondary_text</item>`  in `<style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` of `style.xml`

There is my screenshots when running in android 8.1 and android 4.4

**Android 8.1**

[image]

**Android 4.4**

[image]

Then, I changed the `Next` tab By following operations.

1. I create a new style in `styles.xml`, there is code.

```html
 <style name="my.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">#488FCE</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#488FCE</item>

    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">#ff0000</item>
    
    </style>
```

2. I use this style in Toolbar.axml

[image]

Here is code, Please notice is `app:popupTheme="@style/my.Base"` , not `android:popupTheme`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"

app:popupTheme="@style/my.Base"

/>
```

There is my screenshots when running in android 8.1 and android 4.4.

**Android 8.1**

[image]

**Android 4.4**

[image]

There is my demo, you could refer to it.
https://github.com/851265601/ToolbarItemDemo1

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please try to mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.